# How to concat rows to column depends on values of column?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follow,

    `id    sensor    degree
'--------------------------
    50    temp1     40
    52    temp2     36
    58    temp3     29
    60    temp4     74
    64    temp5     51
    67    temp6     46`


    `id   room     areaA    areaB    areaC
'-----------------------------------------
    1    roomA    temp2    temp4    temp6
    2    roomB    temp3    temp1    temp5`

One is tempture sensor table which are collect all tempture values from sensors setted around a house, and a room table to indicate which those sensors are in the room.
My question is how do I use sql to get table as

    `id   room     areaA    degree-A    areaB    degree-B    areaC    degree-C
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    roomA    temp2    36         temp4    74         temp6    46
    2    roomB    temp3    29         temp1    40         temp5    51`

Many thanks!

Comment: just rotate your monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about `JOINS`, in this case you can have the desired result-set using the `left join` where you will have to do the join with `table1` multiple times with 2nd table depending on the `area*` values which is `sensor` in the first table

So the query will look like

```
select 
t2.id,
t2.room,
t2.areaA,
p1.degree as `degree-A`,
t2.areaB,
p2.degree as `degree-B`,
t2.areaC,
p3.degree as `degree-C`
from table2 t2
left join table1 p1 on p1.sensor = t2.areaA
left join table1 p2 on p2.sensor = t2.areaB
left join table1 p3 on p3.sensor = t2.areaC
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll take your advice to improve my sql skill.